# How to force asp.net GridView control to wrap first row within <thead> </thead> tags

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview, render

I want to use [Christian Bach's tableSorter client-side table sorting jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) with my asp.Net GridView control.

But the problem is, in the documentation it writes:

> tablesorter works on standard HTML
>   tables. You must include THEAD and
>   TBODY tags:

And unfortunately asp.net renders my GridView only with   tags and header row stays within  as the 1st row.

I have tried:

```
   dgvRate.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

after calling .DataBind();

It only helped to have `<TH></TH>` within the header . But still everything is inside `<tbody>`

Can I accomplish this, I mean moving my 1st row from `<tbody></tbody>` to `<thead></thead>` ?

I do not want to add it manually on PreRender stage; I am sure this could be handled much simpler, isn't it?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you have to give it an accessible class to get this to trigger, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  dgvRate.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
  dgvRate.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
  dgvRate.HeaderRow.CssClass = "headerclass";
}
```

Though, for consistency in behavior in all cases I would **go the PreRender route**.

Comment: It does not work with my gridView. Maybe bcoz I create my GridView columns dynamicaly on the code-behind. (I have tried your suggestion on a simple asp.net GridView and I confirm that it works there)

Comment: @burak - Yes, adjusting the columns dynamically fires a lot of events, are you setting this after manipulating the columns for the last time?

Comment: Perfect! I have moved this to OnPrerender and it worked.
thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks Nick for the answer, which partly worked for me : OnPostBack, the new table doesn't generate the thead and tfoot !!! Any clue ? I also get  "The table must contain row sections in order of header, body, then footer." sometimes...

Comment: I found an answer to my question : I put the code in the gridview prerender (had it in the page prerender)...